# Emails not rendering properly on outlook app but works on browser

Tags: outlook, zurb-foundation, html-email, mailjet

I am sending emails from a spring app via mailjet , the emails are rendering properly when open them with the web version of [outlook](https://outlook.live.com) as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w57zx.png) and even on the outlook mobile app but when i use the desktop version it gets  completely messed up like shown on this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRJLL.png)
PS : i am using [foundation](https://get.foundation/emails.html) for the styling you can find the html/css code [here](https://onecompiler.com/html/3wxdn5pzv)

Comment: Could you share the HTML code of your email?

Comment: you can find it on this [link](https://onecompiler.com/html/3wxdn5pzv)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the rendering engine used in Outlook. Microsoft Office Outlook uses the HTML parsing and rendering engine from Microsoft Office Word to display HTML message bodies. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.